# Haskell System.Process Handing

Tags: linux, haskell

I wish to get output from Linux command fortune -a -s and put into irc channel. I have to load System.Process to access.

```
rawSystem("fortune" ["-a", "-s"])
```

returns an exit code and the fortune string, both of which I want to capture.

I know I need to use a tuple, but keep getting an error.

```
(status, fortune) <- rawSystem("fortune" ["-a", "-s"])
```

so that I can process both the exit code (status) and fortune (string).

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with Linux though.

Comment: Windows does not have fortune command

Comment: Windows is not the only other os. Many BSDs, Unix, and OS X systems have fortune or package managers that include it.  My point is the Linux tag won't result in an audience any better at answering the question, it just causes noise.

Comment: Quick note that `rawSystem("fortune" ["-a", "-s"])` is not correct syntax. It will be parsed as `rawSystem ("fortune" ["-a", "-s"])`. Function application in Haskell is not indicated by parens, just by spaces: `rawSystem "fortune" ["-a", "-s"]`.

Answer (score 1):

According to Hackage, [`rawSystem` returns type `IO ExitCode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.3.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:rawSystem), but [`readProcess` does basically what you want](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.3.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess). Was able to play around with this in `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> :m System.Process
Prelude System.Process> ec <- rawSystem "fortune" [ "-a", "-s" ]
There once was a girl from Spokane,
Went to bed with a one-legged man.
    She said, "I know you--
    You've really got two!
Why didn't you say so when we began?"
Prelude System.Process> :t ec
ec :: GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode
Prelude System.Process> out <- readProcess "fortune" [ "-a", "-s" ] ""
Prelude System.Process> :t out
out :: String
Prelude System.Process> out
"The truth about a woman often lasts longer than the woman is true.\n"
```

Comment: I think what they want is actually `readProcessWithExitCode`.